# Make screen reader read "16" as "sixteen"

Tags: html, numbers, accessibility, screen-readers

I currently have a form element with a label:

```
<label for="number">16-digit number</label>
```

This is read out by OS X El Capitan's VoiceOver Utility as **"1 6 digit number"** but I would like to get this to read as **"Sixteen digit number"**. Is this possible? If so, how?

I have tried the following:

```
<label for="number"><span>16</span>-digit number</label>
<label for="number"><span style="speak-numeral: continuous !important;">16</span>-digit number</label>
<label for="number"><span style="speak-as: normal !important;">16</span>-digit number</label>
<label for="number"><span style="speak-numeral: continuous !important; speak-as: normal !important;">16</span>-digit number</label>
```

And possibly some other option I cannot remember. Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

---

If anyone finds this after a struggle, please comment with some of your *failed* search terms to help others find this useful info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
<label for="number">
  <span class="sr-only">sixteen</span>
  <span aria-hidden="true">16-</span>
  digit number
</label>
```

Where `sr-only` is:

```
.sr-only {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking an answer, I was on holiday (vacation). This works beautifully, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

After calculating text alternative for the label ("*16-digit number*"), it reads it as well as possible considering *16-digit* as a single word (and some sort of alphanumeric acronym).

So the different CSS instructions you put inside the `label` tag can't have any effect because the text alternative has already been computed.

You can use `aria-label`:

```
<label for="number" aria-label="16 digit number">16-digit number</label>
```

You can also try to add an invisible pause, or some kind of character in place/supplement of the hyphen. The following might work depending on the way Voiceover calculates text.

```
<label for="number">16-&shy;digit number</label>
<label for="number">16&dash;digit number</label>
```